# How to obtain the negative rational numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

Is there any formula for generating negative rational numbers? Can Calkin–Wilf tree be used for negative numbers?

Comment: Yes, it's very easy to take the Calkin-Wilf tree and put a negative sign in front of each entry...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Multiply the value at each vertex by $-1$.

Bob's yer uncle!

Doing so demonstrates that that the set of negative rationals, like the set of positive rationals, is countably infinite.